# Neumann problem in case f=1

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Is there a solution to the following problem?
 $-\Delta u = 1$ in $\Omega$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$.
where $\Omega$ is bounded.

Comment: Try it on an interval first?

Comment: Look up "strong maximum principle". For example around page 33 or 34 of Gilbarg and Trudinger, _Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order_

Answer (score 1):

I $\Omega$ is a bounded domain, the answer is **NO**. Because of
$$\int_{\Omega}\Delta v dx=\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\nu}ds.$$